# Separating data from user input.

Tags: c, linux, gcc, command-line-interface, user-input

I am writing a program that accepts a command and then gives back the result depending on the command. For example I have command "prime 20" which gives 20 prime numbers and other is sort 1 20 31 45 which will sort the numbers in descending order. This is gonna run in while(1) loop. I have got many of these commands I want to get each numbers separate like 1,20,31,45.My question is how can i parse the data from these commands? I am taking the input in char* but when I access the i index to get number it just gives me first digit if it has one digit. 
Thanks.

Comment: Looking for [strtok](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) ?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking to use the function "[strtok](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok)" to break the spaces into many separate strings and the "atoi" function to convert the nubers in ASCII To Int 
The website in the link gives example of using the strtok function, because it can be a little difficult to understand just reading the man of the function.